# probability rules for complements of events

Tags: probability

Could anyone please help with rules for complements of events- I have difficulty grasping these.

Specifically, suppose there are two events $A$ and $B$, and the corresponding complements  are denoted by $A'$ and $B'$

> What is $\def\P{\operatorname{\sf P}}\P(A'\cup B')$ and $\P(A'\cap B')$ when:
>
> - (i) $A$ and $B$ are independent, and
> - (ii) when $A$ and $B$ are not independent.

(From some previous examples, it seems $\P(A'\cup B') = P(A') + P(B') -1$ in the independent case but I am not sure if this is correct and why this is so.)

Any intuitive explanation would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Study your "previous examples" again.  They should not be telling you that at all.

Comment: Hint: de Morgan's Laws for set operations.$$A'\cup B' = (A\cap B)'\\A'\cap B'=(A\cup B)'$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the probability rule for the complement of event is the following:

Let $ A $ be any event and let $ A^c $ be the complement of $ A $. And let $ P(A) $ be probability of event $ A $ happening.

Then $ P(A^c)  =  1- P(A) $ .

Now, let's solve specifically for your example:

**Case (i)**  $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Because of independence $ P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B) $

By De Morgan's Law $ A^c \cup B ^c = (A \cap B)^c  $

Then

$ P(A^c \cup B^c ) = P((A \cap B)^c)=1-P(A \cap B) $. Since $ A $ and $ B  $ are independent, $ P(A^c \cup B^c) =1- P(A)P(B) $.

By De Morgan's Law $ A^c \cap B^c  = (A \cup B)^c $

Then

$ P(A^c \cap B^c) = P((A \cup B)^c) = 1-P(A \cup B)=1-(P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)) = 1- (P(A) + P(B) - P(A)P(B)) = 1-P(A) - P(B)+P(A)P(B) $

**Case (ii)**  $A$ and $B$ are not independent.

The only difference in this case is that you need to use conditional probabilities. So, instead of  $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B), $ we need to use $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B|A)=P(B)P(A|B)  $.

By De Morgan's Law $ A^c \cup B ^c = (A \cap B)^c  $

Then

$ P(A^c \cup B^c ) = P((A \cap B)^c)=1-P(A \cap B) $. Using conditional probabilities above  $ P(A^c \cup B^c) =1- P(A)P(B|A)= 1- P(B)P(A|B) $.

By De Morgan's Law $ A^c \cap B^c  = (A \cup B)^c $

Then

$ P(A^c \cap B^c) = P((A \cup B)^c) = 1-P(A \cup B)=1-(P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)) = 1- (P(A) + P(B) - P(A)P(B|A)) = 1-P(A) - P(B)+P(A)P(B|A)=1-P(A) - P(B)+P(B)P(A|B) $

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Denson No problem. Please accept my answer so I can get reputation points. :)

Comment: Hi G.T apologies am new to this. Not quite sure how to accept- but will do so once I figure it out

Comment: @Denson Welcome. This is great place indeed and you will love it!